# Is there a simple way to make a drag and drop reorderable list in React Native with items that can move freely in all directions?

Tags: react-native, expo, dropshadow, reorderable-list

I'm working on a React Native app and need to create a reorderable list with specific functionalities. While I've managed to implement basic drag-and-drop using react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated, I'm struggling with making it reorderable.

What I need:

1. Reorderable List: Users should be able to drag list items to reorder them.
2. Moving freely in all directions: This part is currently working using the packages mentioned above, but make it reorderable at the same time is a problem.
3. Drop Shadow: While dragging an item, I want to display a shadow at the potential drop location, giving users visual feedback on where the item will be placed upon release. I'm unsure how to dynamically update this shadow based on the item's current drag position.

All packages i have found for reorderable lists have been only horizontal but i need it to be able to move in any direction.Additionally I need to track how much an item has been dragged to the sides for additional functionalities, like triggering specific actions based on the drag distance.

Anyone done something similar or knows how to implement this?

Comment: You can check this package [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-flatlist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-flatlist). I am using the same and it can help you in knowing the implementation also.